# Azure Site Recovery ARM, blank Account field when adding physical servers

Tags: azure

Trying to add physical servers to ASR under ARM.

I get a blank fiel "account" When I configure "4 Properties - configure properties"

Any ideas what account is needed and where to configure it?

Kind regards[Picture of the error or blank field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktKJz.jpg)

Asger

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to add the account on the configuration server. Account is used to push updates via portal.

Funny thing is that it is not possible to protect machines without that prerequisite.

Hope this helps someone else.

Regards